# Defining default xtype of items in extended class

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have these extensions:

```
Ext.define('Common.view.superstuff.SuperCheckboxGroup', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.CheckboxGroup',
    alias: 'widget.supercbgroup', ...

Ext.define('Common.view.superstuff.SuperCheckbox', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Checkbox',
    alias: 'widget.supercb', ...
```

Is there a way to have `Common.view.superstuff.SuperCheckboxGroup` default to `xtype: supercb` for the items?

I've tried approaches like this:

```
Ext.define('Common.view.superstuff.SuperCheckboxGroup', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.CheckboxGroup',
    alias: 'widget.supercbgroup',
    items: {xtype: 'supercb'}, ...
```

And:

```
Ext.define('Common.view.superstuff.SuperCheckboxGroup', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.CheckboxGroup',
    alias: 'widget.supercbgroup',
    config: {
        items: {xtype: 'supercb'}
    }, ...
```

But these don't work.

I've confirmed if I do specify `xtype: 'supercb'` in the checkboxes when the checkbox group is created, it does work okay.

Just wondering if it's possible to define the default `xtype`?

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-cfg-defaultType

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Evan Trimboli noted in the comments, the [defaultType](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-cfg-defaultType) property allows you to configure the default xtype for child items.

```
Ext.define('Common.view.superstuff.SuperCheckboxGroup', {
  extend: 'Ext.form.CheckboxGroup',
  alias: 'widget.supercbgroup',
  defaultType: 'supercb', ...
```

A related property that allows further default values for child items is the [defaults](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-cfg-defaults) property; you can also configure the default type in that fashion.

```
Ext.define('Common.view.superstuff.SuperCheckboxGroup', {
  extend: 'Ext.form.CheckboxGroup',
  alias: 'widget.supercbgroup',
  defaults: { xtype: 'supercb' }, ...
```